# Extract one pattern or another from output - not entire line

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk, grep

For my immediate task at hand I'm trying to extract specific output from an nmap ping scan, but this question may be more for general gratification because I just don't seem to "get it".

It's pretty easy to simply print the line matching those exact patterns, but I want to do more than that.

For example

```
nmap -sP 1.2.3.4 | awk '/seems down/ || /is up/{print}'
```

Will give me

```
Note: Host seems down If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
```

or

```
Host is up (0.025s latency)
```

Basically I just want to extract the "Host seems down" OR "Host is up" portion.  More specifically I'd like to cull out "Host[whatever is between]down OR up", because sometimes different version of nmap will give different output (but always have the words Host, down or up).  Like if there is a way to match and display any pattern starting with Host, ending at down or up, and stopping there.  I'm thinking this can be done with a sed one-liner, but so far I've only be able to REMOVE "Host" and "down" or "up"...which means I'm just getting something backwards.  Though my lack of regex, sed, and awk experience is what's holding me back the most.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: You can't do it fully universally, (without knowing the output of different versions of `nmap`) because the line `Host seems down If it is really up, but` contains BOTH of words `down` and `up`. So, you should minimally define than what "down" and "up" is relevant... It is easy to search exact phrases "seems down" and "is up"...

Comment: Yeah...that's my bad for not being specific in my thoughts.  I was wondering if there is a way to match and display any pattern starting with Host, stopping at down or up, and stopping there.  I'll edit.

Comment: yes, the `grep -oP 'Host.*?(down|up)'` is stops searching when find the FIRST down or up.. see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A version with grep:

```
grep -oP '(Host.*down|Host.*up)'
```

or a version what show up to FIRST occurence of "down" or "up". Non greedy match between `Host` and `(down|up)`.

```
grep -oP 'Host.*?(down|up)'
```

prints

```
Host seems down
Host is up
```

or even more precise,

```
grep -oP 'Host.*?\b(down|up)\b'
```

what makes the words "down" and "up" word boundary, so for the input

```
Note: Host seems upper down If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
```

prints

```
Host seems upper down
```

Comment: That works nicely!

On nmap version 3.70:
        nmap -sP 8.8.8.8 | grep -oP 'Host.*?(down|up)'
        Host google-public-dns-a.google.com (8.8.8.8) appears to be up


On nmap version 6.40:
        nmap -sP 8.8.8.8 | grep -oP 'Host.*?(down|up)'
        Host is up

Answer (score 0):

Using sed it might be easier:

```
sed -nr '/seems down|is up/s/^.*(Host [a-z]+ (down|up)).*$/\1/p' file
Host seems down
Host is up
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use grep:

```
nmap 1.2.3.4 | grep -oP '[hH]ost (up|seems down)'
```